# new line separated parameters regarded as one positional parameter in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a bash script `myScript.sh` which simply prints the first parameter of the script:

```
$  cat file.txt
1
2
3
4 

$  cat myScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

And if I run the script it returns what I expect:

```
$ cat file.txt | xargs ./myScript.sh
1
```

however, if I try to preserve the new lines in the original file, the list is passed in as **one** positional parameter to the shell script.

```
$  cat file.txt | xargs -0 ./myScript.sh
1 2 3 4
```

I'm wondering what triggers this behavior? It also looks like the input list got an implicit field splitting (similar to what happens in a command substitution) in this case.

Comment: Please explain *exactly* how you are passing the parameters. Normally, if you enter them as you said, after you enter `myScript.sh param1` and press return, it'll go ahead and run the script with just that one parameter, and not wait for the others at all. So you have to be doing *something* unusual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviours you see are normal behaviours.

You first set of commands :

```
cat file.txt | xargs ./myScript.sh
```

xargs collects arguments and run following commands

```
./myScript.sh "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

which is fairly easy to understand.

You second set of commands :

```
cat file.txt | xargs -0 ./myScript.sh
```

As there are no NUL characters in file.txt, xargs collects the whole standard input and run following command with a single argument:

```
./myScript.sh $'1\n2\n3\n4\n'
```

The argument contains well the newlines you wanted to preserve.

But the command you put in myScript.sh makes it appear there are no newlines.

If you change myScript.sh as follows :

```
$  cat myScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "$1"
```

You'll see the newlines.

Answer (score 2):

The problem `xargs` was designed to solve is that there is a limit to the size of a shell command line. And that limit used to be pretty small.  These days the limit is reasonably large but you can still exceed it easily enough, in which case `xargs` is still a useful tool.

So `xargs` expects that the command it is invoking can take multiple parameters and use all of them. That's pretty common; consider `grep` or `ls -l` or `wc` or ... What `xargs` does is to repeatedly gather as many arguments as it can fit into a command invocation, and call the command with all of them.

So it takes an input stream consisting of a number of arguments. By default, these arguments are separated by whitespace, so there could be multiple arguments on a line. But since these days it's more common for filenames to include whitespace, this feature of `xargs` became a liability. It would be possible to make each line in the input a separate argument, but the most general solution is to separate arguments with a NUL character, thus allowing an argument to include a newline.

(Arguments to shell utilities cannot include NUL characters. So using NUL as a delimiter does not add any restrictions.)

You can give `xargs` your own maximum number of arguments to use for a single invocation. And you can even set that maximum to 1. So you can, if you want, use `xargs` to run a command on each of the arguments in a file. That's occasionally useful, but it's not very efficient. Usually a better solution is to write the commands to take multiple arguments, as with the original design. But if you want to use `xargs` in this way, see the `-n` command-line option, among other possibilities.